# Java builder paradigm for database entities

Tags: java, enums, constants, string-literals

I am busy developing a SQL query builder util which will allow me to easily and quickly write SQL queries.  I have the fundamentals sorted for the actual query builder but I am stuck when it comes to using some form on String literals/constants for the database entities (i.e. the tables and columns).
What I would like is to do something like this:

```
String sqlQuery = queryBuilder.select(Tables.Users.FirstName)
.where(Tables.Users.Age >= 10)
.build()
.toString();
```

I've read up quite a bit on enums and how to nest them but it seems like I will have to create an enum for every table (each containing specific columns).  If possible I would like to have one class, which contains all the tables and for each table all the columns.
This should allow me to "build" a string literal by simply calling something like:

```
Tables.Address (returns the string value for 'address' table)
Tables.Address.Country  (returns the string value for 'country' column)
```

This is what I've tried so far using enums but not quite what I wanted.

```
public enum Table {
    Users("users"),
    Addresses("addresses"),

    private String tableName;

    Table(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return tableName;
    }
}

public enum Column {
    ID(Table.Users, "id"),
    NAME(Table.Users, "name");

    private Table table;
    private String columnName;

    Column(Table table, String columnName) {
        this.table = table;
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, tables aren't supposed to be known at compile time. Hence any form of constants is not going to apply.

Comment: You might want to give a bit more information on the Database type that you're trying to work with here. Metadata is definitely the way to go, but the way of getting that Metadata varies hugely as the DB vendor changes.

Comment: Not if it's relational databases.  Java JDBC gives you vendor-agnostic access to database metadata.

Comment: JPA, eclipseLink (criteria builder, generators of schema classes), JOOQ, and others do it. Take a look and maybe you can do better, say with java 8 means. Part is byte code analysis, turning compiled code `x < y` and such into symbolic notation. (NetBeans has a nice JPA, eclipseLink, integration.)

Comment: @GrahamNicol: I am using SQLlite. I will be looking into Metadata and how I can use it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

First, I do not really understand why are you trying to reinvent the wheel that has been already invented many many times.

So, if you are developing library in order to use it take a look on [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/). If however you really want to develop your own query builder you may probably find as useful my project [BeanCrumbs](https://github.com/alexradzin/BeanCrumbs).

Comment: The project I'm working on is really just a small learning project to better grasp database dev in Java.  I'm starting at the very basics and then working my way up/forward. Thus, I felt it necessary to initially write out the SQL queries... In other words, refactoring in waves where I make it simpler and simpler.  Eventually, once I have a clear understanding of how the underlying fundamentals work, I would use a library to achieve this.

Might sound like a round-about way of doing things but I like to clearly understand what it is I am working with and towards.
Thanx for your answer.

Comment: Good luck with your learning, this is an ambitious project but if you stick with it you'll get a great understanding of how the parts of a DB work together, and if you choose to later extend it, how this is done in different DBs.

Answer (score 0):

Enums aren't the way to go; they aren't flexible enough.  You need to access the metadata for each database schema you attach to.

I never see why solutions like yours are considered better than just writing SQL and executing it with JDBC.  It's just as much work to use your builder as it is to write SQL.

FYI - You realize that you aren't the first or the best attempt to solve this problem.  Spring JDBC template takes the boilerplate and work out of interacting with relational databases.  iBatis has been around for a long time and is well proven.  There are lots of ORM solutions, like Hibernate, but those are a bridge too far.  I wouldn't recommend those.  JPA is built into Java EE spec.

I would not want to work on a team that reinvented this wheel and forced me to prefer it over commodity, proven solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [ActiveJDBC](http://javalite.io/activejdbc) quite successfully.
See first point in Design principles, this is as far as it goes in applying "convention over configuration" principle